# How do I edit my post instead of adding comment

Tags: discussion

I have posted a question, having acted on a suggestion, how do I edit my post instead of adding comment? I have a terminal feed-out to post.

Comment: There is a edit link under the post. That's what I think you're trying to find. Is it?

Comment: If not, can you perhaps take a screenshot to show us what you do see?

Comment: I believe you want to edit your recent question "Software Download". You can click on [this](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1103063/edit) to get directly into editing. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 12):

Clicking “edit” under your post leads you to https://askubuntu.com/posts/1103063/edit (if I guessed the question correctly), where you can edit your question and add information:

[image: screenshot]

Please remember to use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting), especially for terminal output.